# Why was Katie Holmes from "Batman Begins" replaced by Maggie Gyllenhaal as Rachel Dawes in "The Dark Knight"?

Tags: dc, behind-the-scenes, nolan-batman-trilogy

I was thinking about this the other day, and it is still one of the things about the Nolan-Batman trilogy that is still kind of irksome to me. Don't get me wrong, I loved Maggie Gyllenhaal as Rachel in *The Dark Knight*, but I still felt it would have had a more emotional impact if Katie Holmes had returned for the role, as we had already had an entire film to get to know the character. Does anyone know why Katie Holmes was replaced?

Comment: Similar question from sister site [Why didn't Katie Holmes play Rachel Dawes in The Dark Knight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/why-didnt-katie-holmes-play-rachel-dawes-in-the-dark-knight)

Comment: So in the Prime Universe, Maggie Gyllenhall was in [Mad Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Money_(film))?

Comment: this question suits more to Movies.stackexchange. Isn't it?

Comment: @HBhatia why? It's perfectly on-topic here. That would be like me going to M&TV and commenting on every SF&F question "Wouldn't this suit SFF better?"

Comment: @hbhatia maybe, maybe not. OP already made the call. So long as it is not offtopic "here", there is really no need to suggest posting "there". Non technical stacks have tons of overlaps. There are [seven death note questions on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdeath-note%5D+is%3Aquestion)... Would they fit in Anime? Yes. Can they be asked here? hell yes.

Comment: Gotcha guys!! @Edlothiad

Comment: @HBhatia while I see (kind of) why you said it, I'd be interested to know what would be different for this question to be asked on M&TV, on a different question someone said because of production details, which I don't know if they're on-topic over at M&TV. So your reasoning is of interest to me as if a case did come up it would be 100% worth migrating

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Katie Holmes chose not to reprise her role as Rachel Dawes

According to Nolan, via alloy.com, Katie was "unavailable for the role",

> Katie wasn't available for the role, which I wasn't very happy about, but these things happen, and I was very, very fortunate that Maggie was able to take it over.
> <sub>[Christopher Nolan sourced by alloy.com](http://www.alloy.com/entertainment/the-dark-knight-director-disappointed-katie-holmes-turned-down-role/#ixzz4S4eIu5rI)</sub>

Maggie Gyllenhaal even sought out Katie's blessing when taking the role, due to her respect for the actress.

> I wanted to be sure, first of all, that I had her blessing,” Gyllenhaal explained. “And I was assured that I did. I'm a big fan of hers, I think she was really great in the first movie.
> <sub>[ibid.](http://www.alloy.com/entertainment/the-dark-knight-director-disappointed-katie-holmes-turned-down-role/#ixzz4S4eIu5rI)</sub>

Katie Holmes says it was a decision she made at the time but not one she regrets making.

> It was a decision that I made at that time and it was right for me at that moment, so I don't have any regrets. I think that Maggie did a wonderful job.
> <sub>[Interview with Business Insider](http://uk.businessinsider.com/katie-holmes-interview-all-we-had-2016-12?r=US&IR=T)</sub>

She also said that she had given up the role to work on her new movie (at the time) *Mad Money*

> "I had a great experience working with Christopher Nolan [and] I'm sure it's going to be a great movie," she said. "I chose to do this movie ['Mad Money'], and I'm really proud of it".... "I was so excited to work with Diane [Keaton] and Queen Latifah and [director] Callie [Khouri]."
> <sub>[Interview with MTV](http://www.mtv.com/news/1579619/dark-knight-absentee-katie-holmes-full-of-regrets-not-at-all-actress-says/)</sub>